# Search shows strange result count

Tags: search, search-results

I am using SharePoint 2013, the site is an Enterprise search site.

When I was searching, e.g. typing `general` in search box it shows 2 pages and 3198 results. Then I click next page, it show 3 pages and 2002 results, I click next page again, it shows 4 pages and 1839 results.

Why are the results different?

I think the result number should be consistent. I found the same question asked before, it was said this is by design, is that true? [the same question asked by somebody else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807862/sharepoint-2013-search-shows-strange-result-count)

Answer (score 1):

This has always been the case, the initial search gives you a fuzzy result or an approximation. As you page through the result set, the number becomes more and more accurate as it parses through the results. This has functioned in this manner since 2007 version at least and is similar to every search engine you'll find on the web.

Comment: Yes, Many people say Google does the same thing. However, I found out it's not true when I done some searching via Google. Google always return the same number regardless which page you click